# IntelliSense missing

Tags: razor, intellisense

I'm using VS2012 and Razor.
In my cshtml-file I have the following :
[image]

As you can see the "@model" and other codeblocks aren't displaying in yellow.
I'm also missing the intellisense.

What am I forgetting?

Comment: Did you try to restart VS? If yes, try to disable all plugins and if it works, add them back one at a time so you find the criminal.

Comment: Does your application get compiled? And check whether your DepositDetailDTO model is there and you can view the definition

Comment: The application compiles just fine. The model exists but when I push F12 when I'm on the model on the cshtml I'm not jumping to the definition

Comment: ok is your model in an External assembly? If so how it is being referenced? Is it just pointing to the DLL? or Is there a project reference? If it's a project reference only you could view the definition.

Comment: And one more thing you could try. Do a clean build. First clean the solution by right clicking on Solution and then do a rebuild.

Comment: I tried the clean solution and the rebuild, but it didn't help.